# decimal64 data type use in C

Tags: c

I want to use decimal64 data type in my c program and I found one library and  that library accept string and convert to deciml64. It is okay. But if I want to get that decimal64 I have to convert it into string then I can get the value. Here is that code...

```
// example5.c -- decimal64 conversions

#include "decNumber/decimal64.h"             // decimal64 and decNumber library
#include <stdio.h>                 // for (s)printf

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  decimal64 a;                     // working decimal64 number
  decNumber d;                     // working number
  decContext set;                  // working context
  char string[DECIMAL64_String];   // number->string buffer
  char hexes[25];                  // decimal64->hex buffer
  int i;                           // counter

  if (argc<2) {                    // not enough words
    printf("Please supply a number.\n");
    return 1;
    }
  decContextDefault(&set, DEC_INIT_DECIMAL64); // initialize

  decimal64FromString(&a, argv[1], &set);
  // lay out the decimal64 as eight hexadecimal pairs
  for (i=0; i<8; i++) {
    sprintf(&hexes[i*3], "%02x ", a.bytes[i]);
    }
  decimal64ToNumber(&a, &d);
  decNumberToString(&d, string);
  printf("%s => %s=> %s\n", argv[1], hexes, string);
  return 0;
  } // main
```

Actually I want to use that decimal64 value in somewhere instead string format.

Below are code snippet

```
decimal64FromString(&a, argv[1], &set); //convert string to decimal64
decimal64ToNumber(&a, &d); //convert decimal64 to decNumber
decNumberToString(&d, string);//convert decNumber to string
printf("%s =>",string);
```

But if I want to use decimal64 data type i.e variable a it is not displaying actual value but if I see variable string it is showing actual value.

### Output

My Input String 0.003
If I print that decNumber i.e variable d
printf("Deciml64toNUmber..%g",d) and the output will be
3.3777e-110 // it is not 0.003

But if I print
printf("D64ToString..%s\n",string); and the output will be
0.003 which is okay.
Now I need the decimal64 value not in string format

Comment: `Actually I want to use that decimal64 value in somewhere instead string format`: please, explain what you want to do. The library appears to have methods to perform arithmetical operations on type `decNumber` (e.g.: `decNumberAdd()`), and you can convert `decimal64` to `decNumber` using `decimal64ToNumber()`.

Comment: I want that decimal64 to pass one of my order engine.  If I use the decNumber it is not displaying the actual value. To get the actual value I need to convert  decNumber to string again.

Comment: Please, edit your question and add the code you tried, and where it fails.

Comment: @LucaPolito I edited the question, any other code can be solve my problem. I have trying but won't.

Comment: @KamilCuk because decimal64 is being converted to decNumber and decNumber again converted to string whatever I found.

Comment: Regarding your very last statement at bottom of your question, can you please edit question to show an actual string value  and its resulting number value, and/or a number value and actual string result from your work.  That will help to clarify what you are asking, and what problem you are seeing.

Comment: @ryyker I added my output with some description.

Comment: Why don't you use some right Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library, i.e. [GNU GMP](https://gmplib.org/) ?  Check [GMP totorial](https://people.inf.ethz.ch/fukudak/lect/mssemi/reports/01_rep_DiyoraSalimova.pdf)

Answer (score 5):

In your code snippet, variable `a` is of type `decimal64`, which is a kind of "opaque" type, i.e.: you can only use `a` with the provided functions that operate on `decimal64` values (in particular, `decimal64ToNumber()`).

The same concept can be applied to variable `d`, which is of type `decNumber`: you can only use `d` with the functions that accept `decNumber` as parameter.

If you want to perform arithmetical operations on `a`, you must first convert it to `decNumber` (using `decimal64ToNumber()`).

If you want to *display* the value of `a`, you may use `decimal64ToString()` to convert it to string. You cannot read the actual value of `a` without first converting it to string. (An alternative is to use `decNumberToString()`, if you already converted `a` to `decNumber`).

That means that, for instance, this is *not possible*:

```c
printf("%g\n", d);
```

Because neither `decimal64` nor `decNumber` are native C data types supported by `printf()`.